# Bootstrap progress bar rounded

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I wish to know if it's possible to make the bootstrap progress bars circles instead of straight lines. If is possible I will like to know how is don. if not then I think the bootstrap guys should integrate this option in bootstrap 4

Comment: look this http://www.cssscript.com/pure-css-circular-percentage-bar/

Answer (score 6):

You can try this following snippet, it worked for me..

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Basic Progress Bar</h2>
  <div class="progress" style="border-radius: 10px">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%; border-radius: 10px">
      <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think what he means is that the bar itself forms a circle rather then a straight line. Not that the corners are rounded.

Comment: Well, maybe I did not explain myself enough. I meant that the whole bar to be an arc, not a straight line, but in your example, you just rounded the edge of the progress bar.  **Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/kimmobrunfeldt/mxjj6jom/)**